# Deciding between Electric or Hydraulic Actuators for a Dynamic Load of around 4 kN to 6 kN

Tags: mechanical-engineering, electrical-engineering, hydraulics, robotics, actuator

This is a project regarding linear actuators for a 4 Wheeled Robot, with spider like hinged legs. The first question on my mind was to figure out is if a hydraulic system has any weight to Force(strength) advantage on this load category of max 6 kN to an electric-mechanical system with a brush-less motor. Since its a mobile unit and has to be water and dirt resistant.

Also most important question is what Force class does the hydraulics start to outshine the feather weight electric actuators?
**Spider Robot needs to operate within the parameter:**

- *dynamic load of max 6 kN*
- *operated with 12 V battery pack.*
- *quick actuation speeds at least 6 mm/s*
- *brush-less DC motor 1000 W (**with Feedback**) preferred in electric or hydraulic systems for efficiency.*

Thank you for any advice or for sharing your experiences.

Comment: A key benefit of hydraulics is that you can put the motor somewhere separately, and then the pistons wherever you can run a hose. This is good when you have a central power source e.g. engine on a digger, but pistons everywhere e.g. arm on a digger. Is this a requirement for your project?

Comment: yes, but the most important requirements right now are actuators using Brush-less motors with feedback, as far as i have checked online, none of the companies make them. And for the hydraulic the same brushless motor could be used to operate a pump upto 120 Bar roughly. The core idea first is to figure out the power source then will decide on the location of the cylinders. Thank you for the response.